# PHP Exec Permission Denied

Tags: php, linux, compiler-construction, permissions, exec

I am trying to compile a file using PHP. The PHP Code is...

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $filename= "source/source.c";
    $fp = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($fp, $_POST['answer']);      
    // Now compile...       
    echo system("gcc $filename 2>&1");


}
```

I am getting the output as

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file a.out: Permission denied collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 1
```

I don't know what is wrong with the code or permissions. I am on Ubuntu 11.04 using LAMP Stack. 
I've tried chown the folder to www-data and chmoding to 777 . But I am still getting the same error.

Any guidance on what to do is highly appreciated :)

Thanks Already,

Best Regards

Aman Gautam

Comment: Check permissions specifically on a.out. Also once you do `chmod`, verify again with `ls -l`

Comment: You are compiling user input through gcc?

Comment: I hope that this is just a personal project, and not anything on a public facing system. This is a major security issue if you are planning to make this publicly accessible.

Comment: @Pawan: Yes, I double checked it :( It belongs to www-data and 777 permission

Comment: @Joedanm: Yes. Do i have a better option to compile using a web interface? :)

Comment: @jncraton: Yes, I am learning PHP and Linux :)

Answer (score 2):

Check the permission of the output directory, i see a $_POST, so it's seem to be apache who run the script, check if apache can write in the directory, and also override the existing a.out.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But How can I do it? There is a user www-data. But how can I give permission to a process?

Comment: Two solutions : chmod -R o+rw (or chmod -R 666) on the directory you use. You need to give to the www-data user the complete access to the directory, if you don't want other process to have access, you can use ACL, but it's more complicated.

Comment: Do a ls -ld on the directory you use to see the permission the www-data has.

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked permission and it is 777 , but still does not work , you may check if app armor or se Linux active in your system. To disable app armor :

> AppArmor can be disabled, and the kernel module unloaded by entering
>   the following:
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor stop
>
> sudo update-rc.d -f apparmor remove
>
> reboot